# Blazor WebAssembly cannot load resources files from class library

Tags: c#, blazor, embedded-resource, webassembly

I'm currently working on a Blazor WebAssembly Asp.NET hosted in .NET Standard 2.1.

I try to load resources files from a separate .NET Standard 2.1. C# Class library.

Unfortunately I always get the following error:

***"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not load type of field 'MyNamespace.Footer:k__BackingField' (0) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.Resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies."***

1. My .resx files are set to **Access Modifier: Public** and look like this in the properties tab:

[image]

My project structure looks like this:

- MyNamespace.BlazorApp.Client
- MyNamespace.BlazorApp.Server
- MyNamespace.BlazorApp.Resources

I load the resources like this:

2. *MyNamespace.BlazorApp.Client:*

In my Program.cs Main Method I set the current culture like this:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

and I add the Localization service:

```
services.AddLocalization();
```

Further on in a .razor page where I want to use the culture setting I inject the Localization service:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<Translations> Translations
```

3. **MyNamespace.BlazorApp.Server**

Here I simply load the project reference to my resources project. I don't use the .resx in this project.

Do you know how to load resources from an external .NET Standard 2.1. C# Class library into a Blazor Wasm project?

Comment: Shooting blindly... Does the 3rd party have `AddRazorSupportForMvc` in the project file? ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#razor-class-library

Comment: Still quite a few details are missing: Where is Translations defined (ns & asm), what is the folderstructure?  What is the exact name of the resx files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from a name clash, the project can be compiled but not loaded.
I know a way to get it working, I'm not sure is this is the only or best way.

1. Rename your resx project to `MyNamespace.BlazorApp.Translations`
2. Make sure there is a public class Translation in the root (no 's')
3. Make a Folder called `Resources` in the Translations project
4. Add Translation.resx, Translation.es.resx etc to that folder
5. Change the config to `builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");`

Resources is a default name at several places, not a good idea to name your own project the same. The ResourcesPath seems to be required, I don't know what the defaults are.